# Create two colors in ListViewItem background

Tags: uwp-xaml

Is there any way to have the background of a ListViewItem in uwp to be seen as two different colors like in [this control?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxZ5V.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

You can set the background of the `ListView` itself and set the color there:

```xml
<ListView>
   <ListView.Background>
       <!-- some background, probably linear gradient brush
            with sharp stop between the two colors -->
       <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
          <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.2" />
          <GradientStop Color="CornflowerBlue" Offset="0.2" />
       </LinearGradientBrush>
   </ListView.Background>
</ListView>
```

The alternative is to set the background color of each item separately:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.2" />
                        <GradientStop Color="CornflowerBlue" Offset="0.2" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks!